# Make Cell active after running script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to reset the active cell to K2 after running this script.Can anyone help me with this?

```html
if(count==0){// If no matching part number is found give message.
    Browser.msgBox( "Part Number "+inputPartnum+" Not Found" );
    ssheet.getRange('K2').clear();
    ssheet.getRange('L2').clear();
    ssheet.getRange('M2').clear();
}}
```

Comment: Have you visited this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26187361/triggering-script-by-specific-cell-value)? Have you tried using [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
     ssheet.getRange('K2').activate();
```